# analytics attribution first vs. last click

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Suppose the following scenario:

- User visits a blog
- User goes to my domain via blog, with a specifically tagged link (source/medium) for that blog only
- Session cookie expires
- A week later, the same user (same browser) goes to google and searches for my domain
- He enters my domain through paid ad
- He converts on my website

Is there a report that attributes the user conversion to the blog's source medium? As I understand it, although the session expires the firs click will be attributed to the blog referral, and the last click would be google ad / cpc, because google knows the same user first interacted via referral.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

As long as that person is on the same device, you can make that report in the Model Comparison Tool part of the Attribution reporting. You can set the attribution to what you want, and you could use 'first click' as your preferred attribution model.